# How to compare IDs with comma separated string in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, for instance "Employees" and "Projects". I need a list of all projects with the name of all the employes involved.
Problem now is, that the employe_ids are saved with commas, like in the example below:

```
employe  | ID          project   | employe_id
--------------         -----------------------
Person A | 1           Project X | ,2,
Person B | 2           Project Y | 
Person C | 3           Project Z | ,1,3,

select 
p.project, e.employe
from 
projects p
left join employees e on e.id = p.employe_id ???
```

How do I have to write the join to get the desired output:

```
project   | employe
--------------------
Project X | Person B,
Project Y |
Project Z | Person A, Person C
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with. Do you have the option to fix that broken data model?

Comment: It's not my database. Unfortunately I have to live and work with it :-(

Comment: I imagine you're going to have to write a script that pulls the comma separated ids, removes the commas storing the results in an array that you can then run against the other table.  though I'd talk to the client about changing the way they're storing the data to follow best practices.

Comment: "Person C" is associated with ID = 3. Why do you have this person showing up in the results for "Project Z"?

Comment: Oh you are right. I fixed the example :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `group by` and `listagg` as following:

```
select 
p.project, 
listagg(e.employe,',') within group (order by e.id) as employee
from 
projects p
left join employees e on p.employe_id like  '%,' || e.id || ',%'
Group by p.project
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kind of fun way to do it:

```
WITH cteId_counts_by_project AS (SELECT PROJECT,
                                        NVL(REGEXP_COUNT(EMPLOYE_ID, '[^,]'), 0) AS ID_COUNT
                                   FROM PROJECTS),
     cteMax_id_count AS (SELECT MAX(ID_COUNT) AS MAX_ID_COUNT
                           FROM cteId_counts_by_project),
     cteProject_employee_ids AS (SELECT PROJECT,
                                        EMPLOYE_ID,
                                        REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMPLOYE_ID, '[^,]',1, LEVEL) AS ID
                                   FROM PROJECTS
                                   CROSS JOIN cteMax_id_count m
                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m.MAX_ID_COUNT),
     cteProject_emps AS (SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT, ID
                           FROM cteProject_employee_ids
                           WHERE ID IS NOT NULL),
     cteProject_empnames AS (SELECT pe.PROJECT, pe.ID, e.EMPLOYE
                               FROM cteProject_emps pe
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES e
                                 ON e.ID = pe.ID
                               ORDER BY pe.PROJECT, e.EMPLOYE)
SELECT p.PROJECT,
       LISTAGG(pe.EMPLOYE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pe.EMPLOYE) AS EMPLOYEE_LIST
  FROM PROJECTS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cteProject_empnames pe
    ON pe.PROJECT = p.PROJECT
  GROUP BY p.PROJECT
  ORDER BY p.PROJECT
```

You can certainly compress some of the CTE's together to save space, but I kept them separate so you can see how each little bit adds to the solution.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4281213fc7beab45f324309ccc408bd0)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the numeric IDs from the `employee_id` column of the `projects` table by using `regexp_substr()` and `rtrim()` ( *trimming the last extra comma* ) functions together, and then concatenate by `listagg()` function :

```
with p2 as
(
select distinct p.*, regexp_substr(rtrim(p.employee_id,','),'[^,]',1,level) as p_eid, 
       level as rn
  from projects p
connect by level <= regexp_count(rtrim(p.employee_id,','),',') 
)
select p2.project, listagg(e.employee,', ') within group (order by p2.rn) as employee
  from p2
  left join employees e on e.id = p2.p_eid
 group by p2.project
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=98c9a085e73e6d1934b73b93914bb7a5)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barbaros, your code works fine for 1 or 2 employees, but not with 3 or more.

Comment: Hi @Philipp, you're right. I've fixed changing the style.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option; code you need (as you already have those tables) begins at line #12:

```
SQL> -- Your sample data
SQL> with employees (employee, id) as
  2    (select 'Person A', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'Person B', 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'Person C', 3 from dual
  5    ),
  6  projects (project, employee_id) as
  7    (select 'Project X', ',2,'   from dual union all
  8     select 'Project Y', null    from dual union all
  9     select 'Project Z', ',1,3,' from dual
 10    ),
 11  -- Employees per project
 12  emperpro as
 13    (select project, regexp_substr(employee_id, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) id
 14     from projects cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 15                                                  connect by level <= regexp_count(employee_id, ',') + 1
 16                                                 ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 17    )
 18  -- Final result
 19  select p.project, listagg(e.employee, ', ') within group (order by null) employee
 20  from emperpro p left join employees e on e.id = p.id
 21  group by p.project
 22  /

PROJECT   EMPLOYEE
--------- ----------------------------------------
Project X Person B
Project Y
Project Z Person A, Person C

SQL>
```